# Wordpress search results order

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a problem with pagination on results. I need to order the results by title and by alphabetic order (A->Z) , its possible? I tried some different approaches but none work as needed, the best i have so far is list the results by title and ASC but if i go to "next page" i get always the same results.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are on the right track but you are getting the same results on each page because Wordpress is losing track of what page it is on internally. This is done with the $paged global.

If you are modifying the sorting with query_posts, make sure you are also passing in the global $paged var ('&paged='.$paged ). Also, make sure that global exists on the page as well before calling it in query_posts, otherwise it will always be 0 and return the same results on each page. If you are using WP_Query instead of query_posts, this is a good run down. http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using, add it on index.php

```
<?php
$posts = query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc');
?>
```

In your case, you might also need to put is_home() condition

```
<?php
if(is_home()){
global $query_string;
query_posts($query_string . '&orderby=title&order=asc');
}
?>
```

Hope it helps :)